# PHP preg_match_all

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I would like to ask about php's preg_match_all. suppose we have the sample string below:

> This is a clause with -*value1*- and -_value_2_- having a subclause of -*value.3*- items.

And i would like to extract all strings with the opening "-*" and closing "*-" characters. Needed output should be:

```
Array  
(
[0] => Array  
    (
            [0] => -_value1_-  
            [1] => -_value_2_-  
            [2] => -_value.3_-  
        )  
)
```

Comment: And... what have you tried? Seems a simple enough [regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

Comment: regex i tried is "/-_.*._-/" but its returning a wrong result.. not so verse in regex patterns:(

Comment: /(-.*?-)/ or /(-.*-)/U  or without ( and )

Comment: @JadeRyanIbarrola: you might want to make that `*` [ungreedy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.repetition.php) (appending the `?` like Cheery says.

Comment: many thanks Cheery^_^ and Wrikken, this worked for me: "/-.*?-/"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one of the following simple regexps `/-.*?-/` or `/-.*-/U`

> U (PCRE_UNGREEDY) This modifier inverts the "greediness" of the
>   quantifiers so that they are not greedy by default, but become greedy
>   if followed by ?. It is not compatible with Perl. It can also be set
>   by a (?U) modifier setting within the pattern or by a question mark
>   behind a quantifier (e.g. .*?).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
$str="This is a clause with -value1- and -_value_2_- having a subclause of -value.3- items.";
if (preg_match_all('/-[^-]*-/', $str, $m))
      print_r($m[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes `preg_match_all()` can be too complicated. In these cases you can use `explode` for this aim.

```
$matches = explode("-", $input);
```

What `explode()` does?

```
$input = "This is a basic example: -JOHN-. The End";
```

`explode()` converts `$matches` to an array. After that searches `$input` for "-" character. After finding the "-" it will set array like below.

`$input[0]` --->  "This is a basic example: "

`$input[1]` --->  "JOHN"

`$input[2]` --->  ". The End"

`explode()` is an alternative way. But the best one is of course `preg_match_all()`

Answer (score 0):

You could use [T-Regx library](https://t-regx) that automatically adds delimiters

```
pattern('-.*?-')->match($string)->all();
```

the result is

```
Array  
(
      [0] => -_value1_-  
      [1] => -_value_2_-  
      [2] => -_value.3_-  
)
```